# Page not found not working if settings.DEBUG:

Tags: python, django

I started studying the Django library and ran into a problem when creating an online store that my page could not be found when using the following command:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

son/urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('koil.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')



DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in son.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

When the server starts, it writes this:
admin/
^static/(?P.*)$
^media/(?P.*)$
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

What could be the problem?
P.S. I apologize in advance if the question is asked incorrectly, if necessary, I can add.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve this problem(